# JQuery validate error class for error message vs. input field

Tags: jquery, validation, error-handling

I have a field that I am trying to validate with the jQuery validate plugin. I have defined the error class to turn the text red:

```
.error {
    color:#FF0000;  /* red */
}
```

However, this class gets applied to both the text of the input field as well as the error message underneath. What is the easiest way to only apply the "error" class to the error message, not the input text? Seems like this should be the default behavior. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the message below the input text is a label you can restrict the CSS to label like this

```
label.error {
    color:#FF0000;  /* red */
}
```